# Iterating through excel sheets and write it all in separate sheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, openpyxl

I am new to python.
I'd apreciate every good and detailed explanation/correction.

> I am reading every [.xlsx](/questions/tagged/.xlsx) file in such manner that my dictionary keys are the names of the sheets.
> Every sheet is composed by a DF with the same format (identical column names in all of the sheets).

Is there any way to iterate across all of the sheets? I want to repeat the same action on each sheet and consider them as separate DataFrames.
Let's say that I would like to create a fourth column by concatenating the second and third column from every sheet and write the result in a new [.xlsx](/questions/tagged/.xlsx)file

```
# Defining the Libraries I am expecting to use.

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as op
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

# Defining my file and the DF

my_file = r'\\user\Desktop\my_excel_file.xlsx'
my_dfs = pd.read_excel(my_file, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)

# Defining the action I would like to perform in every sheet.

for keys in my_dfs:
  my_dfs['concatenation'] = my_dfs['Name'].map(str) + my_dfs['Surname'].map(str)
  column_to_move = my_dfs.pop('concatenation')
  my_dfs.insert(4, 'concatenation', column_to_move)
```

I am trying to obtain something like the image below (for everysheet).
And eventually write the new DataFrames in a separate sheets, whose name will be the same as in the original file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hujD9.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. When you read your file, you get a dict of DataFrames. Just iterate over the dict of DataFrames an perform whatever you want to do on each DataFrame.

Comment: Hi Filip, thanks for reaching out. The problem is that I should open each sheet individually and I would like to do everything in one go.

Comment: What do you mean by `open each sheet individually` and by ` do everything in one go`?

Comment: That I should write **my_dfs.get(sheet_1)** to start operating with my first sheet, instead, I would like to write the instructions just one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_excel('my_excel_file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)
for sheet_name, df in dfs.items():
    df.insert(4, 'concatenation', df['Name'] + ' ' + df['Surname'])

with pd.ExcelWriter('my_excel_file.xlsx', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    for sheet_name, df in dfs.items():
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

Comment: I think there were a couple of mistakes here. The output obtained is __AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'insert'__

Comment: @machukovich It would help if you pointed to the issue(s).

Comment: Thanks for your goodwill @Filip. As I mentioned before, df is not defined yet.

Comment: @machukovich You did not mention that before, you edited your comment. `dfs` should of type Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]`, hence `df` is a `pd.DataFrame`. `df` get's defined in the loop. You are doing something wrong and not calling the code that is in my response.

Comment: You were right , I don't know what I was doing wrong. But now I copied your code and it seems to work. Thanks for your feedback.